# ImmutableJS programatic key naming?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I want to be able to create a Map and programmatically name the index. is
this impossible because Javascript is dynamically typed and Map needs a string?

for more context in case I am missing a better pattern: i get a bunch of person objects (name, id) from server, and now initialize a profile Map.

```
export function makeMap(person) {

 const profileMap = Map({
   person.id: Map({
     id: person.id,
     name: person.name,
     foo: false,
     otherthing: 5,
     favorites: Map({}),
   })
 })
```

Comment: Try changing it to `[person.id]` for the key.  The `[]` should make it evaluate to a string for the purposes of the key

Comment: Beat me to it. I'll just add that it's called a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Now we just need someone to find an (surely) existing duplicate, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're asking but if you want to use the value of the persons id as a key in an object it would look like:

```
const { id, name } = person
const profile = {
  [id]: {
    id,
    name,
    foo: false,
    otherthing: 5,
    favorites: {}
}
```